# Dereferencing a pointer to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Referring to the line with the comment:

- Why does adding parenthesis in the example work to print all the contents of the array?

The example prints "one", then prints garbage.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const char* a[3] = { "one", "two", "three" };
    const char*(*p)[3] = &a;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << *p[i] << std::endl; // this line
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works after changing to this:

```
std::cout << (*p)[i] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`p` is a pointer to an array of 3 elements like this:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│     │     │     │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
   ^
   └─ p
```

Note that it points at the whole array, not a single element of it.

The expression `*p[i]` is treated as `*(p[i])` due to operator precedence (which is equivalent to `*(*(p + i))`). This means that you are indexing the pointer to the array. If you do `p[1]`, for example, you move the pointer along to the "next" array and attempt to dereference it:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│     │     │     │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
                     ^
                     └─ p + 1
```

As we can see, there is nothing there, and you'll get undefined behaviour. However, when you do `(*p)[i]` (equivalent to `*((*p) + i)`), you are making sure the dereference happens first. The dereference gives us the array itself, which can then be implicitly converted by array-to-pointer conversion to a pointer to the arrays first element. So what you get is:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│     │     │     │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
   ^
   └─ *p
```

In this case, the pointer is pointing at the array *element* and not the whole array. If you then index, for example, `(*p)[1]`, you'll get:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│     │     │     │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
         ^
         └─ (*p) + 1
```

This gives you a valid `const char*` which can then be outputted by `cout`.

Comment: Great answer. I didn't realise that increasing i would try to dereference another whole array, though I was aware of operator precedence. I must be stuck in the mindset of an array being a pointer.

Answer (score 7):

[Operator precedence.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)Without `()` operator `[]` will be called first and result of it will be `dereferenced`. With `()` - firstly will be `dereference` and then call to operator `[]`.

Answer (score 4):

[Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

The array selection have higher precedence than dereference, so from the compilers point of view it's really:

```
*(p[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;       

        int main() {


            int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

            int *p=arr;


            int intgerSize=sizeof(int);


            for(int k=0;k<5;k++)


            {  
                cout<<"arr ["<<k<<"] "<<*(p+(k*sizeof(int)/intgerSize));  
                cout<<"  "<<(p+(k*sizeof(int)/intgerSize));
                cout<<"  "<<p+k<<"\n"; 

            }`enter code here`

            return 0;
        }
OUTPUT:- 
arr [0] 1 0x7ffd180f5800  0x7ffd180f5800
arr [1] 2 0x7ffd180f5804  0x7ffd180f5804
arr [2] 3 0x7ffd180f5808  0x7ffd180f5808
arr [3] 4 0x7ffd180f580c  0x7ffd180f580c
arr [4] 5 0x7ffd180f5810  0x7ffd180f5810
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @ankitgupta.  As questions and Answers are saved and serve as a resource to help not only the individual asking the question, it is useful to include an explanation of how/why this code addresses the questioner's issue.  You can edit your answer to include additional information.  You may want to review:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Above code will help you to get an idea how compiler internally handle array.