# Exception thrown when trying to change a pointer in a void function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, void

I am trying to make a void function where it changes the pointer that I pass. The code is throwing an exception on one of the lines and i'm not sure why. Could it be I cannot pass the arrays as pointers then implement math on it? I thought I deallocated the pointers to fix it but this seemed to not work.

Void function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void* func2(int one, double *value1[], int two, double *value2[], double  *final1) {
    double testval;
    double finalval = 0;
    //double *final1;
    double final = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < one; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < two; j++) {
            testval = *value1[i] * *value2[j]; //exception thrown (works up to this point)
            finalval = testval + finalval;
        }
        final = finalval + final;
    }
    *final1 = final;
    return 0;
}
```

Main Function:

```
int main(){
    double *array1 = new double[input1];
    double *array2 = new double[input2];
//for loop that takes user input and fills in array1 and array2 with size and a list of values
...
double testval2;
func2(input1, &array1, input2, &array2, &testval2);
cout << testval2 << endl;

delete[] array1;
delete[] array2;
return 0;
```

I am relatively new to pointers, so my apologies if the code is a little illiterate.

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: Hmm... having trouble finding a precise duplicate, but [What is a pointer to an array of x amount of ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617112/what-is-a-pointer-to-an-array-of-x-amount-of-ints/40617252)  combined with [Dereferencing a pointer to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013450/dereferencing-a-pointer-to-an-array/16013550) comes close.

Comment: I did not go through your code completely but, you cannot use `final` as variable name in `c++`, [final](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) is identifier in c++

Comment: @pvc See [keyword @ cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword): `final` is one of the "*identifiers with special meaning,* which may be used as names of objects or functions, but have special meaning in certain contexts."

Comment: @JaMiT, your right, thanks for pointing me to the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to pass two 1D arrays to `func2()`.

One way to do that is remove the `[]` from the function signature as

```
(int one, double *value1, int two, double *value2, double *final1)
```

Within the function, change `*value1[i]` to `value1[i]`, and similarly for `value2`. And remove the `&` when calling the function from the main().

A couple other thoughts:

- I'm not sure how an exception could throw from your code. But `*value1[i]` is definitely an invalid memory access, so what you may have seen is a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) message. A helpful tool to troubleshoot these kinds of errors is [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer), enabled in clang or gcc by compiling with `-fsanitize=address`, or if you are using Xcode, there is [an option for it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_memory_thread_and_crash_issues_early). Another great tool is [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/).
- Manually allocating dynamic arrays is a pretty C-like way of using C++. In C++, it is idiomatic to create the arrays as `std::vector` objects, which under the hood works the same way (it also allocates a dynamic array) but has a more convenient interface. Particularly the vector cleans itself up automatically, so no need to call `delete[]`, and the vector knows its own size, so no need to pass the size around as a separate parameter as with dynamic arrays.

**Edit**: Here is a note to clarify why the original code manages to compile but fails at runtime.

In the function signature, the combo of both `*` and `[]` on `double *value1[]` makes `value1` a pointer to a pointer to double, equivalent to `double **value1`. In main(), `array1` is a double*. When calling the function, `&array1` takes the address of that double*, obtaining a double**. So the type matches and the code compiles.

The code fails at runtime on `*value1[i]`. value1 is a pointer to pointer to doubles, where the inner pointer points to the dynamic array. So what was intended is `(*value1)[i]` to first dereference the outer pointer, then subscript into the dynamic array. However, in C++, subscripting (`a[]`) has operator precedence over dereferencing (`*a`), so it is read in backward order as `*(value1[i])`. Subscripting the outer pointer `value1[i]` is invalid for nonzero `i`, reading memory from somewhere in the stack and arbitrarily interpreting it as a double*. Then the surrounding `*( )` attempts to dereference this busted pointer. The machine's memory protection catches this, and the OS sends a "SIGSEGV" signal or similar to the program to kill it.

Comment: Thank you! I assume my & on array1 and array2 was part of the problem, although im not sure why. If you could explain that I would love to learn why so I do not make that mistake again. Otherwise, this solved the problem!

Comment: Good question. I edited my answer above to dig into this.